# SQL - What am I doing wrong with this "Insert Into Select" Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have to fill up a database with test data, and my database is related to delivery. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Insert into Orders (OrderCode, OrderDate, Insurance,QuickDelivery, PackageNumber, ClientID, AdressID, DeliveryID, OrderStatusID)
    Select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 20),
           D.OrderDate,
           FLOOR(RAND()*(1-0)+0),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(1-0)+0),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(5-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(200-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(704-505)+505),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(200-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(9-5)+5)
    from Deliveries D join
         Orders O
         on D.OrderID = O.OrderID
    where D.OrderDate = FLOOR(RAND()*(200-1)+1)
```

Either way, in the table Deliveries I have tons of randomly generated examples, just the OrderID and a random Date, and I'm trying to select some dates from that table and insert them into this one, so the order dates and delivery dates match. Either way my idea was it to pick a random ID from the table and that to take that record's date and insert int into the Orders table. When I tried declaring a variable with some random date and inserted it into the parameter list the query worked so I must be missing something with this join or something. It's required for me to have at least 1000 records so this is a really long process which I'd prefer not to do manually. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.  Your query looks syntactically correct.  Clearly you are having some issue, but I cannot determine what it is from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pick up randome dates from `Deliveries`, then you do not need `Orders` in the `select` query.  This should be sufficient:

```
Insert into Orders (OrderCode, OrderDate, Insurance,QuickDelivery, PackageNumber, ClientID, AdressID, DeliveryID, OrderStatusID)
    Select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 20),
           D.OrderDate,
           FLOOR(RAND()*(1-0)+0),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(1-0)+0),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(5-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(200-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(704-505)+505),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(200-1)+1),
           FLOOR(RAND()*(9-5)+5)
    from Deliveries D ;
```

You can add `top (n)` to the `select` query to insert a certain number of rows (if the rows are available).

Comment: This worked, thank you, I was overthinking it too hard with joins I guess.